# getting a repatted generated answer in python

Tags: python-3.x, math

I am trying to make a program which can help me on finding Area using Radius. but its output is very weird, take a look!

```
Pi = 3.1415929203539825
print('What is the Radius') #asking for Radius
R = input()
A = str(Pi) * int(R) * int(R)
print("The Area of this circle will be " + str(A) + "")
```

when R = 5, this is what it outputs:

```
3.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.14159292035398253.1415929203539825
```

Comment: You multiplied a string. Multiplying a string *repeats the string*.

Comment: Why did you convert `Pi` to a string?

Comment: Change `str(Pi) * int(R) * int(R)` to `Pi* int(R) * int(R)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast pi to a string. Doing so repeats the string

Try this instead

```
from math import pi
R = float(input("enter a radius: "))
A = pi * (R**2)
```

Comment: thank you very much! as u might not know, I'm only 12 and I only had 2 hours worth of coding expirience :)